# How to Stub a series of HTTP requests and test the UI of a web application

Tags: javascript, selenium, user-interface, testing, ui-testing

I have an ELM application which communicates with an HTTP server to fetch  data. I would like to test its UI upon different type of API responses. A test would look something like:

1. Start the app
2. Serve to the app some static data
3. Check the UI behavior
4. Serve some other data
5. Check UI again

and so on.

Such a generic use case has probably a lot of solutions - I'm looking for personal recommendation based on your experience. Preferably, I would like to code these tests in Python (Selenium?) and/or JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not (AFAIK) so straightforward as it may be (unless web app you want to test already supports mocking on its side) but you can setup the web driver to use a profile where you configured a proxy server: requests will be redirected there and you can then provide the mocked response you want. See also http://mock-server.com/#what-is-mockserver